# OpenERP: develop or modify a module?

Tags: odoo

I am currently working on a project whose goal is inventory management (warehouse) using OpenERP. After having determined the needs, I found that the module offered by OpenERP is too broad.

Is it preferable to develop my own module or to modify the existing knowing that I find it very complicated?

Comment: Please ask answerable questions, answering this depends on so much things, type of module, your expertise level, etc.

Comment: I am a beginner in openerp.Sorry, if I was not too clear to understand the purpose of my question.Thank you for your feedback

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's better to use the existing module, hiding the parts you don't need in overloaded views if needed to mask the unneeded complexity. It will save you valuable development and maintenance time, as well as guaranteeing a correct integration of the warehouse management in the rest of the ERP.

Do not modify the existing module. Write anotherone exending the existing with missing fields, customized views, extended workflows and new wizards.

Comment: Thank you very much Gurney for your answer, I think you understood my question

Answer (score 1):

Ya you can customized a module for your own use basically goal of openERp is that user can customise and use there own module so we are adding some fields same as you can remove fields which you dont want.